# Connecting to Socket server on Android using Telnet

Tags: android, adb, telnet

I have a ServerSocket running on my Android app in an emulator. I would like to send messages to it from my host machine (a MacBook).

Following instructions exactly from [How to connect to an Android server socket in the emulator](https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-an-android-server-socket-in-the-emulator) , my steps are:

1. Start a new thread in the Android app. Within this thread, use a
   ServerSocket to listen to incoming requests on port 8080 and local
   IP address.

   ```
   InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(< ipaddress >);
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080, 0, addr);
   clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
   ```
2. Use ADB to redirect network traffic from a host at port 5050 to 8080.

   ```
   telnet localhost 5554  
   redir add tcp:5050:8080
   ```
3. Use Telnet to send a message to host at port 5050. This message is expected to be redirected to port 8080 on the emulator. Instead, I get a connection close message.

   ```
   telnet -d localhost 5050
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
   Connection closed by foreign host.
   ```

Any idea why would the connection get closed immediately? What can be done to send the message to the server?

Comment: I'm following the same instructions and ran into the same issue. It looks like sometime between when that was posted in 2012 and this question in 2018, the emulator stopped allowing incoming connections. The lack of a descriptive error message or updated [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection) makes it look like either a bug or we're doing something wrong.

Comment: [This](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect/Android_Emulator) might help. I wasn't able to get it working for my needs (ARM emulator for a project without x86 support) and a telnet test didn't work, but I was able to get pings to go through to an x86_64 emulator. That's as far as I got before giving up, since it's not a problem on physical devices.

Answer (score 1):

the emulator cannot be accessed from the host on `127.0.0.1` but it's `10.0.2.2`

... else you would connect to the local loopback, instead of the virtual interface.